# What is the opposite of mod_wsgi-express start-server

Tags: linux, apache, server, mod-wsgi

I accidentally closed the terminal after running this command

```
mod_wsgi-express start-server
```

And I can't find the resource on how to stop the server

What is the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution
I opened terminal and killed the process via the pid

I opened the terminal and ran the following code to get the pid of the process

```
lsof -i -f
```

This is a sample response I got

> apache2 20000 ebrahim    3u  IPv4 1234565      0t0  TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)
>
> apache2 20001 ebrahim    3u  IPv4 1234565      0t0  TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)
>
> apache2 20004 ebrahim    3u  IPv4 1234565      0t0  TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)

Then I performed the following command to kill it in the form of sudo kill (pid number) for example

```
sudo kill 20000
```

Another way (more proper way) to do this is to go to the to the directory that holds the apachectl file. (the directory changes if you use the `--server-root option` when using the `mod_wsgi-express start server` command).
You simply have to run the code below from terminal

```
/etc/mod_wsgi-express-80/apachectl stop
```

Comment: Depends on how the terminal session was set up, but normally if you close the window, it should have been killed off automatically as it would have been running as a foreground process. As you found though, if for some reason that didn't occur, running ``apachectl stop``, using the ``apachectl`` in the directory generated by mod_wsgi will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I had run the `mod_wsgi-express` script on a virtual environment on port 5000.I had to run the following command to stop it.

```
/tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:5000:1002/apachectl stop
```